# bash: regular expression not working right

Tags: regex, bash

Please check the code below, I want to label "-n" and "-n.n" as good number. Strings like "-.n" and "-n." are not good number. Where "n" is "[0-9]+".

```
#!/bin/bash
function test_number() {
  if ! ([ -z $2 ]); then
    if [[ ${2:0:1} == "-" ]]; then
      if [[ ${2:1} =~ [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)? ]]; then
        echo "${2}: good number"
      fi
    else
      echo "$2: string"
    fi
  fi
}

test_number "1" "-x"
test_number "1" "-1"
test_number "1" "-1."
test_number "1" "-2.1"
test_number "1" "-.1"
test_number "1" ".1"
test_number "1" "x"
```

This is the test result; the wrong cases are marked.

```
-1: good number
-1.: good number     <== wrong
-2.1: good number
-.1: good number     <== wrong
.1: string
x: string
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: FYI -- `if ! ([ -z $2 ]); then` is both needlessly inefficient and incorrect (if `$2` is empty, it resolves to `[ -z ]`, which is equivalent to `[ -n -z ]`, and thus returns true instead of false). Take out the parenthesis -- they do nothing but slow down your process by adding an extra fork/wait cycle -- and while you're at it, why not change it to `if [[ $2 ]]`, removing the double-negation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
^(-[0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]+)?$
```

Here `^` and `$` are used to match whole string/line that represents start and end of string/line respectively.

Here is the corrected version

```
^-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/zA2zY3/3)

**Note:** remove `?` to make it mandatory for minus `-`.

---

Points:

- Here minus `-` should come along with some digits to avoid `-.n` match
- Decimal `.` should come before some digits to avoid `-n.` match

Comment: OK, I see. All I miss is "^" and "$" at the beginning and end respectively. Your answer is helpful even though it is not correct. Still, thanks!

Comment: You have too many optional parts. The empty string is a match. According to the spec in the question, you want `^-[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$`

Comment: @glennjackman Let me correct it. In your case `.1` is not a match.

Comment: Right. Read the question again.

Comment: @glennjackman sorry now  I am confused. Is the OP looking for negative numbers only?